# What to do with the genetic ramifications of the war?

Tags: social-norms, mutants

After a global nuclear war, most modern civilizations and technology were destroyed. And for reasons unknown, portions of humanity became mutant freaks, either from radiation or some sort of...genetic thing? That doesn’t really matter.

What does matter is that mutantism is embedded in humans genetic code. Every generation, there will always be a child born with all sorts of freaky mutations: neurological problems that make them insane, discolored skin, multiple limbs.

Mutantism has become a recessive trait, like having red hair, and if two people with the gene mate, they will create mutant offspring. Most mutants are a danger to mankind, as they are often mentally challenged, violently insane, and psychotic.

They can’t simply be killed, as the Pope and other religious figures have said that mutants are technically human, and women can not simply have abortions, as technology has been pushed back to the late 1600s, so my question is: how could the wastelanders deal with the mutants humanely? Humanely means no killing or shoving into prison or workhouses.

Comment: 1. You need to outline the question you want "What to do with the genetic ramifications of the war?" doesn't say what’s coming across it should be like "How to deal with children born with mutations humanly" 2. Why can’t humans kill them, humans now kill each other, so even if this pope outlawed it humans will still do ethnic killings or segregation. At the very least the mutants will become second class citizens or slave labour.

Comment: @DTCooper Given that all but a couple of options are eliminated within the question there's nothing left to answer with.

Comment: In real life, with no nuclear war etc., more than 1 in 500 children are born with some sort of genetic disorder, with about 1 in 1000 born with a serious condition. That's not one per generation; it's hundreds per day.

Comment: abortion was still possible in the 1600's, Also what religious leaders say will have little impact on most people. If you want a no fatal way just say so.

Comment: @DTCooper Wikipedia's opening line on the history of [abortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion#History_and_religion): "Since ancient times abortions have been done using herbal medicines, sharp tools, with force, or through other traditional methods.[14] Induced abortion has long history, and can be traced back to civilizations as varied as China under Shennong (c. 2700 BCE), Ancient Egypt with its Ebers Papyrus (c. 1550 BCE), and the Roman Empire in the time of Juvenal (c. 200 CE)."

Comment: @DTCooper : more outline please! In your question it is not unambiguous what is an OR, and what is an AND. Is every mutant visibly different? Is every visibly different (third arm, etc. ) mutant ALSO psychotic AND violently insane AND ...  also, add some numbers - is every 5th birth a mutant, if no precautions in mating are taken? is every 2nd mutant violent? etc.  Without knowing the prevalence of the problem it is impossible to predict anything. 1 per generation could be pampered like a king, being closely watched by guards that catch him in silk-padded restraints until he calms down...

Comment: @John whatever the state of abortion-technology in 1600, the predict-a-mutant-tech (especially if mutants sometimes only have dicolored skin) was nonexistent

Comment: @bukwryn: Every Mutant is unique, but most have disabilities from autism to insanity

Comment: @Cort Ammon: Mutantism can’t be detected

Comment: Medicinally induced abortion has been around for a couple thousand years already - you can thank the chinese for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options:

1. make sure that carriers of mutant genes don't reproduce with each other, a tad eugenics-ish but ultimately a workable solution provided you make tracking your family tree mandatory by law (or have an organization for it). Eventually you'd need to come up with an actual test for the mutant genes better than "did you're great aunt give birth to a mutant freak?" however that can come a while after mankind has rebuilt. Without an actual test for mutant genes it is only a mitigation of the problem and is not a complete solution as you'd be working with estimations for the probability of being a carrier based off of genealogy rather than absolute certainty. it also requires some basic understand of genetics survive the Apocalypse.
2. leper style colonies. if you're not okay with killing prisons or workhouses then you're probably not okay with just taking the problem and pushing it somewhere else but again its an option available to you.
3. specialized parenting (i.e. modern autism parenting): this is probably the best solution as far as being humane goes. if the problem is mutants being born into the society then its possible that their nature could be cancelled out with proper nurture. training the mutants (who are still human) to cope with their metal disabilities from birth while difficult could be done sure if you have learning difficulties due to a mutation in your genes you might not ever be an accountant or lawyer but there's no reason you can't be a contributing member of society. The same goes for psychopathy or any other metal illnesses caused by the mutations even in the actual 1600's plenty of people had severe mental problems but nonetheless went on about their lives.
4. cosmetic surgery. this doesn't need to be the sort of modern Botox and plastic stuff mind it could be as simple "hey doc could use a hot scalpel to remove my second thumb?" procedures like these, while not advisable, were done in pre-industrial societies and are easily doable if you're society can't just grow to accept the discolored skin and extra limbs. (sometimes problems like discoloration could just be covered with cosmetics and lots of arm-length and ankle-length clothes).

Comment: Option 2 is still a prison by any other name.

Comment: If i understand the question of OP , the mutants are dangerous, not just visually different, so option 4 might backfire.

Comment: @bukwyrm Hmm yup that's an angle with some literary scope right there.

Comment: as i understood it not all issues where present in every mutant, some exhibited physical mutations others were effected mentally (though i might be wrong on that) ideally options 3 & 4 would serve as a two-pronged approach

Answer (score 3):

**What DT Cooper Said But Darker**

The ancient Spartans used to cast infants which were determined to be deformed, weak, or otherwise lacking in positive features were thrown off of a cliff. Your society has a nearly religious disdain for mutation or deformity. They immediately kill anyone displaying signs of aberration including infants. I think keeping them around peacefully while nice, wont work. You will simply be creating a genetic reservoir of mutation that will breed more of them. People striving for basic survival needs like food shelter and water don't tend to keep dead weight around either. Abandoning them to the elements isn't really an act of hate for them, its one of survival. They can't feed useless mouths like we can today.

Comment: Okay that's actually more humane than DT Cooper's answer but it still falls short of answering the question _as written_ since that specifically precludes killing off the mutants.

Comment: Except the author of the question has a misunderstanding of what humane actually means. Sometimes humane means euthanasia.

Comment: _And?_ My statement stands, as death is precluded from acceptable answers this cannot be an answer to the question that was written.

Comment: So delete it then.

Comment: Would that I could.

Comment: All you people who are voting to delete this answer as low quality.  Sheesh. It's perfectly reasonable for an answer to be "No, your premise doesn't work."  If you don't like that answer, the correct behavior is to down vote, not delete the answer (or close the question).  WB:SE is having a problem right now because people are using close/delete votes as super-down-votes.  This answer could be improved with better justification, but it's not invalid.

Comment: The problem is people use deletion and closing as a way to shut down answers they don't personally like, instead of as a way to regulate relevancy of the actual answer.

Comment: When you disagree with the premise of a question you can note that in an answer but you should also answer the question that was asked, with the premise intact.  The only time you should offer an alternative and ignore the premise/requirements completely is when the premise is logically inconsistent with itself.

Answer (score -1):

***Abandon Them***

Not the ‘most’ humane way but it is more humane than the other ways. Just get all the mutant babies and leave them near a river or valley. They’ll have to fend for themselves, but you can have someone watch over them or make sure no harm is done.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about issues with this answer has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78400/discussion-on-answer-by-dt-cooper-what-to-do-with-the-genetic-ramifications-of-t).  Remember to [edit] clarifications into the answer instead of just leaving comments (which are not permanent).